# Add content to listview in runtime

Tags: c#, listview

I'm looking for some help to add text to a listview with four columns. One way to add text to a listview is like this:

```
var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] {"text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"});
lvRegAnimals.Items.Add(item1);
```

But I wonder how this would be done in runtime, when a user clicks a button to add new content to all the columns? I'm new to this and I preciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your code to the button click event handler, some thing like this

```
void Btn_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] {"text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"}); 
  lvRegAnimals.Items.Add(item1); 
}
```

Comment: OK, but I guess I cant't use the variable item1 more than once? The point is to add several rows to the listview? user clicks on the button several of times! Then I must use new variables each time?

Comment: No need...each time the user clicks item1 will be initialised and it will be added to your list view....you can try out and see

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that each row in the listview had to be a unique object with a unique variable!?

Comment: only values need to be unique...same object can be used repeatedly

Comment: OK, then I understand it better. But can I replace the "text1", "text2" etc. with just string variables like ....{txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4}); ?

Comment: Nice! It's working! By the way, is there a way to prevent the user from resize the columns?

Comment: The last questions was perhaps a little bit to complicated. I search for an answer, and it seems to be complicated!? Anyway, thanks for the help with adding content to the listview!